# Disable some days in magento calendar

Tags: magento, calendar

I want to use the calendar widget in magento, my question is how can i disable some day ?

i call it like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 Calendar.setup({
    inputField : '_dob',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : '_dob_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true
});
//]]>
</script>
```

If I want to disable all Monday's, for example, how can i do that?

Also if I want to disable all days before 3 days after today how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Calendar.setup({
    disableFunc: function(date) {
        return date.getDay() === 1; // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on
    }
});
```